# Is it possible to run some HTML5 input types in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, html-input

Is it possible to run some HTML5 input types in IE8 with any library??
for example with range.

```
Points: <input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

Comment: You could put that in IE8 and see for yourself.

Comment: Do you know some IE8 emulator?? I tried with IEtester, and not working input type='range'

Comment: It renders as a text box in IE8. Which is kind of too be expected. Don't expect IE8 to support HTML5 widely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modernizr To check if your browser supports HTML5.
And you could use Jquery UI Slider it work in IE8

Check this page : http://jqueryui.com/slider/ 
demo: http://jsbin.com/eduren/1/edit

To read slider value/percentage value:
var val = $('#slider').slider("option", "value");

Answer (score 5):

IE8 doesn't support `<input type="range">`. The most seamless way to accomplish this in older browsers is to detect support and use "polyfills" where needed. A polyfill is designed to add support to older browsers, typically using some JavaScript that tries to emulate what the native behaviour would be.

[This page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) has a great list of polyfills. (And Modernizr is a great way to detect support for these sorts of things.) You'll find polyfills for various input types in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Right of my mind I think of Chrome frame, a Google project to bring Chrome engine under Trident hood.

URL: http://www.google.com/chromeframe

I never tried myself. When a browser experience a bug, we fix it or find a workaround. I'm not a big fan of add-on, especially from an administration point-of-view.

Another option would be to use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library to detect the browser capability and find a work around for it. There is always some hacky way to get your way out. Using [html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) could be a way to find your way out. And that's the second option I prefer when dealing with IE8. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Ie8 will render all "html5" input types as text. However you can then target those types with JavaScript, using something like

```
$('[type=range]').slider() //insert your favorite library here...
```

I know it isn't tagged jquery, but I figure the example is still clear enough

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a range input, then checks if the browser is a version of Internet Explorer that doesn't support range inputs. If that's the case, it creates a range input out of divs and uses some Javascript code to make it interactive.

```html
<input name="range" id="range" type="range" min="1" max="10" />
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <div id="range_ie" style="position:relative; width:255px; height:15px; font-size:0px; cursor:default" onselectstart="return false">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:5px; width:100%; height:30%; border-left:1px solid gray; border-top:1px solid gray; border-right:1px solid white; border-bottom:1px solid white; background:silver"></div>
    <div id="slider" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:5px; height:100%; border:1px solid gray; background:#EBEBEB; font-size:15px" onmousedown="document.onmousemove=changevalue">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Hide the <input> element, otherwise older versions of IE will just display it as a text input
    document.getElementById("range").style.display = "none";

    //If the user releases the mouse after changing the value of the range input, it should stop changing
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
      document.onmousemove = function(){};
    };

    function changevalue(e) {
      //Get the value of the input from the position of the cursor
      range.value = ((navigator.appName.substring(0, 3) == "Net") ? e.pageX : event.x) * (range.max - range.min) / (document.getElementById("range_ie").style.width.substring(0, document.getElementById("range_ie").style.width.search("px"))) + Number(range.min);

      //Check that the value isn't out of bounds
      if (Number(range.value) > Number(range.max)) {
        range.value = range.max;
      }
      if (Number(range.value) < Number(range.min)) {
        range.value = range.min;
      }

      //Move the slider to its new position
      document.getElementById("slider").style.left = (range.value - range.min) * Number(document.getElementById("range_ie").style.width.substring(0, document.getElementById("range_ie").style.width.search("px"))) / (Number(range.max) - Number(range.min)) + "px";
    }

    //If we click on the slider just like that, it should move
    document.getElementById("range_ie").onclick = changevalue;
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```